# Android: Device Unique Hardware

Tags: android, hardware, galaxy

Is it possible to develop applications for Android that take advantage of unique hardware? To be more clear, an example would be the Galaxy S4. That phone has many hardware inputs and outputs that are not exactly standard to the Android model, such as a thermometer, an IR LED, a humidity sensor, and the "Air View" features (not sure what the hardware for that is called).

Is it possible to develop third party apps that take advantage of these? If so how difficult is it?

I have searched this topic and can't seem to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to develop applications for Android that take advantage of unique hardware?

That is impossible to answer in the abstract.

> Is it possible to develop third party apps that take advantage of these?

A [thermometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) and a [humidity sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY) are part of the Android SDK. You are welcome to use `SensorManager` for those, assuming Samsung is exposing those sensors through `SensorManager`.

With respect to the IR emitter, "Air View", etc., it is possible that some of that is available through [a proprietary Samsung SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk).